# Acessing my WebView object from another class

Tags: android, eclipse, android-2.2-froyo

I am creating an Android version of my web browser. I want to be able to load websites from another class using the WebView object that is in my MainActivity class. Basically I want to load a website from a button referenced in the QuickSites class in the WebView object in the MainActivity class. How would I do this?

Comment: pass your `WebView` to class `QuickSites`...

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting the site you want in a separate activity, you can pass back a String using the `setResult(reqCode, data)` where data is an Intent. Create an Intent, add the url to it with `putExtra("url", url)` and call finish(). Then, in your main activity, override onActivityResult to get the url out of the Intent and pass it to the WebView.